# How to migrate Vue .prototype to a separate file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a few functions to put in Vue .prototype
But I would not want to clutter up main .js
I tried to port prototypes like this

```js
//main.js
import "./vue-extensions/prototypes";
```

```js
//prototypes.js
import Vue from "vue";
export default new Vue.prototype({
    $appName = "myName",
});
```

But using this I have an error
` ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                  6:35:11 PM
error  in ./src/vue-extensions/prototypes.js

Syntax Error: D:\Projects\FrontEnd\gta\src\vue-extensions\prototypes.js: Unexpected token (3:19)

1 | import Vue from "vue";
2 | export default new Vue.prototype({

> 3 |   $appName = "myName",

@ ./src/main.js 14:0-37
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.3.200:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js`

Comment: `new Vue.prototype` doesn't really make sense, and you cannot put an assignment in an object literal. Can you please post the code that works if you put it in a single file?

Comment: yeah, for example this works in main.js  — Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution =
  document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 &&
   document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080 ? 1080: 2160

Comment: Well that's something completely different. Where did you get the `export default new Vue.prototype({})` from?

Comment: An alternative would be to define and export your functions (no Vue or prototype) in a separate .js.  Then import those functions in main.js, and set to Vue.prototype in main.js. ```import { function1, function 2 } from functions.js``` ```Vue.prototype.$function1 = function1```, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that *is* a syntax error - an assignment statement inside an object literal.

You don't want to instantiate anything, so don't use `new` . You don't want to export anything that could be imported in main, so don't use `export default`. Just put the code that modifies the prototype object in the module and nothing else:

```
//prototypes.js
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$appName = "myName";
Vue.prototype.$assetsResolution = document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 && document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080 ? 1080: 2160
```

---

An alternative, that makes it clearer what happens (since extending prototype objects you don't own is usually a bad practice), would be to still do the assignment in main.js but define all the values in the separate module:

```
//main.js
import prototypeExtensions from "./vue-extensions/prototypes";

Object.assign(Vue.prototype, prototypeExtensions);
```

```
//prototypes.js
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
    $appName: "myName",
    $assetsResolution: document.body.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio <= 1920 && document.body.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio <= 1080 ? 1080: 2160,
};
```